# Manage connection string

Tags: c#, dapper

I'm using [dapper-dot-net](https://github.com/StackExchange/dapper-dot-net) for data access in my `ASP.NET MVC` application.
So in order to supply a `connection string` I've came up with the following pattern:

```
public static class ConnectionStringManager
{
    private static readonly SqlConnection conn;

    static ConnectionStringManager()
    {
        //initialize the connection with value from web.config file
        conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyConnName"].ConnectionString);
    }

    public static SqlConnection GetOpenConnection()
    {
        if (conn.State != System.Data.ConnectionState.Open)
            conn.Open();

        return conn;
    }
}
```

And a sample use of it with in a query:

```
public Customer GetCustomerById(int id)
{
    string sql = @"select * from Customer where Id = @id";
    using (var conn = ConnectionStringManager.GetOpenConnection())
    {
        Customer cust = conn.Query<Customer>(sql, new { id }).FirstOrDefault();
        return cust;
    }
}
```

So my question is if this is a good approach or not, and if not, what would you suggest to do different?

Answer (score 1):

You create the `SqlConnection` only once, in the type constructor of ConnectionStringManager. Then you wrap its usage in a `using` block which is good practice but will dispose the object when it leaves the scope, so any subsequent usage will result in an `ObjectDisposedException`.

Instead, create a new connection in the `GetOpenConnection` method (maybe rename it to CreateConnection or similar in order to reflect the fact that there's work being done).

Comment: Care to elaborate the downvote?

Comment: Whoa, that's a long shot and I highly doubt it. In that case (single operation), why even bother with a static manager class at all?

Comment: Yeah and in that future scenario my point still stands! With the presented usage pattern the GetOpenConnection method cannot guarantee to do what you'd think it does, judging by its name. It will give you an open connection **once** and only once.

Comment: Ok, last attempt. Do you really not understand what I'm saying? Get**Open**Connection claims to give you an **open** connection on each call. With the presented usage pattern (`using` block) -- which is **good practice** -- you get an **open** connection on the first call **only**. One. Single. Time. On each subsequent call, the method throws an exception.

Comment: because it's a static object....

Comment: what do you think of my answer? is there any fallacy in it?  will it have the same issue as the OP (that you pointed out)?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about calling this a `ConnectionStringManager` as you are not really managing the string for the connection, you are managing the connection itself, well rather opening a connection if the connection is not open.

I don't know if I would use a static class to do this.

You could probably use a factory pattern for this, but you would have to accept a parameter of the string used for the configuration location that holds the connection.  But, what happens if you don't hold the connection strings in the same location?

Here is what it would look like if you created this as a Factory

```
public static class ConnectionFactory
{
    public static SqlConnection GetOpenConnection(string connectionName)
    {
        var conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[connectionName].ConnectionString);
        conn.Open();
        return conn;
    }
}
```

Your usage is the same, except for the name changes and passing in the `connectionName` this decouples the method from the caller,  you could change the connection you want to use for this particular method and not affect any other methods that use this static method.